# How to scope has_many through association that uses custom key names?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

Trying to learn how to properly navigate a has_many through association that I'm working with and I'm hitting a brick wall. I've abstracted the classes here so that they're easier to relate to.

A book has many characters.
A character has many books.
What makes it different from a typical hmt association is that when a character is associated with a book, it is added either as a "good guy" or as a "bad guy", for example:

```
book.bad_guys << character
```

I'm able to pull up results for book.good_guys just fine. What's throwing me for a loop is whenever I want to go the other way, to take a character and find out what books he is associated with, it returns a Book::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy rather than an actual result list.

If I do character.books.first this is what outputs (notice how it attempts to find a "good_guy" attribute rather than go off of the book and character columns that are part of the join table)

```
Document Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "books".* FROM "books" INNER JOIN "book_characters" ON "books"."id" = "book_characters"."good_guy" WHERE "book_characters"."character_id" = ? ORDER BY "books"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["character_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: book_characters.good_guy: SELECT  "books".* FROM "books" INNER JOIN "book_characters" ON "books"."id" = "book_characters"."good_guy" WHERE "book_characters"."character_id" = ? ORDER BY "books"."id" ASC LIMIT ?
from /home/linux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
```

I suspect I need to scope how the Character model carries out it's search through the through table and ultimately to the Book table, but I haven't had any success.

Is it possible to add a scope on the character model to modify how it searches the through table? Or is there something else I need to do to find the associated records? Thanks in advance for any help you can give!

```
class Character < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :book_characters
  has_many :books, -> { where(book_characters: ("character = :character.id")) }, :through => :book_characters # I don't think my wording is correct here

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :book_characters
  has_many :good_guys, through: :book_characters, :source => "character"
  has_many :bad_guys, through: :book_characters, :source => "character"

class BookCharacter < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :character
  belongs_to :book, :foreign_key => :bad_guy
  belongs_to :book, :foreign_key => :good_guy
```

And here is the migration for BookCharacters...

```
class CreateBookCharacters < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change 
    create_table :book_characters do |t|, 
      t.references :book, foreign_key: true
      t.references :entity
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you'd like to be able to make a query like `character.books` and have it return a relation showing all of the books that character is in?

Comment: @quicklikearabbit: Yes, that's what I'm after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem is this:

```
class BookCharacter < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :character
  belongs_to :book, :foreign_key => :bad_guy
  belongs_to :book, :foreign_key => :good_guy
```

There are two problems here. First, you can't double-declare `belongs_to :book`. Second, when you say `:foreign_key => :good_guy`, rails expects that `BookCharacter` is going to have a field called `good_guy`. Which it doesn't. Which is why you get:

```
no such column: book_characters.good_guy
```

So, you need something more like:

```
class BookCharacter < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :character
  belongs_to :book
```

Then, I believe your scope can look something like:

```
class Character < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :book_characters
  has_many :books, -> { Book.where(book_characters: book_characters) }
```

I'm not 100% sure that `book_characters: book_characters` bit will operate as advertised. So, you could try something like:

```
class Character < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :book_characters
  has_many :books, -> { Book.where(id: book_characters.pluck(:book_id)) }
```

Having said all that, I doubt that this:

```
book.bad_guys << character
```

Is doing what you think it is. Because, you don't seem to persist the notion of 'good_guy' or 'bad_guy' anywhere. So, you're probably not really keeping track of who is good and who isn't.

Finally, I noticed you're using SQLite. I have no idea where you'll eventually deploy your app. But, you probably want to think that through. Heroku, for instance, doesn't use SQLite and to deploy on Heroku you would need to convert to postgresql. Something to noodle on.

Comment: Interesting... Thank you for your detailed reply, a lot to chew on! So if I'm reading you correctly, if I'm wanting to segregate out good_buys from bad_guys, it would make more sense to add them as intervening models? Or maybe use some sort of polymorphic association?  The eventual goal is to be able to take a book's good_guys and bad_guys and create an encounter between them, but that encounter would be "owned" by the book, so that's what is prompting the separation... (the real objective is to represent legal transactions between parties)

Comment: There are multiple ways to do what you are after. I wouldn't expect that you need any new models - you could track good/bad guy on `BookCharacter`. But, you'll need a new field there. And, you'll need to change the way you're adding a character to a book (again, multiple ways to go after that). Give it a go and let us know if you have specific questions.

Comment: > "Give it a go and let us know if you have specific questions."  Thank you for your help jvillian, will do! :thumbs_up: